# how to assign count of column to anothe variable in sas?

Tags: sql, oracle, sas

%Let abc = count( no of variables in data set )

Comment: This question is unclear. Do you want to know how to assign the value count to a macro variable or to a datastep-variable? What is count exactly, the number of different columns in a dataset or the number of observations in a column? Please add more details and better description in your question, in this form it is unclear what you are asking, that why you get the donwvotes.

Answer (score 0):

The following code assigns the number of columns in the dataset 'have' to the macro variable **abc**.

```
data _null_;
    if 0 then
        do;
            set have (obs=0);
        end;

    array chars _character_;
    array nums  _numeric_;
    ncharvar = dim(chars);
    nnumvar = dim(nums);
    nvar = ncharvar + nnumvar;
    call symput('abc',nvar);
run;
```